# Convert double to time format

Tags: c#

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC C# Programming

I have a class which contains an attribute called Credits of type double. This attribute should be represented as a Time Format (hh:mm) in my web application. So for example, if I were to give Credits the value of 2.5, I want it to display 2:50, 6.15 as 6:15, etc. I know TimeSpan can convert a double to the time format but it converts 2.5 to 2:30. Is there a way to do easily convert a double to this time format without changing its data type to a String? Is there some sort of helper Attribute tag or something that would make this easy?

Comment: What do you do in situations like `2.75` or `6.31456`?

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: Also please remove unrelated tags. This has nothing to do with `MVC`.

Comment: `it converts 2.5 to 2:30` which is how you would expect fractions of an hour to be converted. Your desired output flies in the face of common math.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to get the whole number and the fractional part separated, and that you want the fractional part as a two-digit number.

So here's how you would get the whole number part as an `int`.

```
var whole = (int)Math.Truncate(value);
```

And this would give you the fractional part as an `int`, in this case only the first two decimal places.

```
var twoFrac = (int)(((decimal)value % 1) * 100);
```

So, if `value` was `12.345`, then `twoFrac` would turn out to be `34` in `int`.

Now you can display these whichever way you like.

And you can actually put the above inside of a method so you can get the fractional part up to however many decimal places you want, like this:

```
private static int GetFractionalPart(double value, int decimalPlaces)
{
    var factor = (int)Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    var fractional = (int)(((decimal)value % 1) * factor);
    return fractional;
}
```

---

### NOTE

However, as many others pointed out in comments, this is a confusing and you could even say wrong way of doing things if you're actually dealing with time values. For example, using your criteria, a value of `2.75` would convert to `2:75`, but that doesn't mean anything in terms of time.

So you really ought to use `TimeSpan` as you mentioned in your original post, which would convert `2.5` to `2:30` etc.